# attach an existing managed disk to a new VM using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I wanted to deploy a vm with managed disks . I have already created a managed disk in another resource group and I want to use this during the template deployment. I am currently blocked here.

I am Using the below parameter here existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup , this has the managed disk I wanted to use it in my template.

parameters:

"existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "poc-rg",
      "allowedValues": [
        "poc-rg"
      ],

varibales:

```
"managedDisklocation":"[resourceId(parameters('existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Compute/disks')]",
"managedDiskpath":"[concat(variables(managedDisklocation),'/poc-manageddisk')]"
```

resources:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "name": "[variables('vmNameMdb')]",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": ["[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('newStorageAccountName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'))]"],
    "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
            "computerName": "[variables('vmNameMdb')]",
            "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
            "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
            "secrets": [{
                "sourceVault": {
                    "id": "[parameters('keyVaultSubscriptionId')]"
                },
                "vaultCertificates": [{
                    "certificateUrl": "[parameters('engineCertificate')]"
                }],
                "vaultCertificates": [{
                    "certificateUrl": "[parameters('vmAgentCertificate')]"
                }]
            }]
        },
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "publisher": "[parameters('imagePublisher')]",
                "offer": "[parameters('imageOffer')]",
                "sku": "[parameters('imageSKU')]",
                "version": "latest"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "createOption": "FromImage"
            },
            "dataDisks": [
            {
                "lun": 0,
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'-datadisk1')]",
                "createOption": "attach",
                "managedDisk": {
                        "id": "[parameters(managedDiskpath)]"
                }
            }
        ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
            "networkInterfaces": [{
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',variables('nicName'))]"
            }]
        }
    }
},
```

**Error:**

Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'managedDisklocation' is not valid: Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': the type 'Microsoft.Compute/disks' requires '1' resource name argument(s). Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Are both resource group in the same Location?

Because resources must be in same region.

Comment: Yes there are in same region but the disk is in different resource group

Answer (score 0):

the Error you got shows the reason:

> 'The template variable 'managedDisklocation' is not valid: Unable to
>   evaluate template language function '

If you want to attach another disk to Azure VM, the disk's location must be same as the orginal one. It means that the **locations of the VM and Disks should be same**.

Comment: I am using this  and got this error :
"dataDisks": [
             {
                 "lun": 1,
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-datadisk1')]",
  "managedDisk":
  { 
  "id": "[resourceId('/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/' , 'vm1_disk100')]"                               }
                    ]
Error:
Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Compute/disks/balacrg7-datadisk1' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Comment: From the error it looks like you have a dependsOn for the existing disk in the template - dependsOn is only for resources defined in the same template (not needed for existing resource scenarios)...  If you can share your template we can see for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code again carefully, not sure why you have 'managedDisklocation' in the 'managedDiskpath' variable.  The 'managedDiskpath' variable should look like below to map to the 'poc-manageddisk' managed disk.

```
"managedDiskpath":"[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/poc-manageddisk')]"
```

Comment: I tried this and failed 

 "id": "[resourceId('/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/yxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm1_disk100')]"

Comment: I was successfully able to deploy VM with attached disk from different resource group but same region

<img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mJ2zG6/20180203_004009_Custom_deployment_Microsoft_Azure.png" alt="20180203_004009_Custom_deployment_Microsoft_Azure" border="0">

<img src="https://preview.ibb.co/kANo9R/20180203_004456_Disks_Microsoft_Azure.png" alt="20180203_004456_Disks_Microsoft_Azure" border="0">

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to able to deploy VM with attached disk from different resource group but same region with template below.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "manageddiskpath": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "vnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/','default')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "Canonical",
                        "offer": "UbuntuServer",
                        "sku": "16.04-LTS",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [
                        {
                            "lun": 0,
                            "createOption": "Attach",
                            "managedDisk": {
                                "id": "[parameters('manageddiskpath')]"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')), '2015-06-15').primaryEndpoints['blob']]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIpAddress": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Basic"
            },
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "default-allow-ssh",
                        "properties": {
                            "priority": 1000,
                            "protocol": "TCP",
                            "access": "Allow",
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "22"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Key area, setting the ResourceID for the managed disk as a parameter, since its static and can't be generated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Circling back to this.  Was this helpful? Did is resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to create new disks and attach them to an existing Virtual Machine that's running. With this, you can attach multiple disks mentioned in the disk count.

> **Important!** Make sure the virtual machine and your created disks belong to same *Resource Group* and *Location*.

### Template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmPrefixName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "vmCount": {
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "type": "Int"
        },
        "diskStorageType": {
            "defaultValue": "StandardSSD_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "StandardSSD_LRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "type": "String"
        },
        "dataDiskCount": {
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "type": "Int"
        },
        "dataDiskSize": {
            "defaultValue": [],
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vmPrefixName'),string(if(greater(parameters('vmCount'),1),copyIndex(1),'')))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "storageProfile": {
                    "copy": [
                        {
                            "name": "dataDisks",
                            "count": "[parameters('dataDiskCount')]",
                            "input": {
                                "name": "[concat(concat(parameters('vmPrefixName'),string(if(greater(parameters('vmCount'),1),copyIndex(1),''))),'_datadisk', string(add(copyIndex('dataDisks'),1)))]",
                                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                                "createOption": "Empty",
                                "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('dataDiskSize')[copyIndex('dataDisks')]]",
                                "managedDisk": {
                                    "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskStorageType')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Parameter.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vmPrefixName": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "value": 1
    },
    "diskStorageType": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "dataDiskCount": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "dataDiskSize": {
      "value": [
        128,
        64
      ]
    },
    "location": {
      "value": "eastus"
    }
  }
}
```